# Need help using a super scope

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

I have a windows server 2008 r2 standard running our DHCP, DNS, and AD. also I have (3) HP Pro Curve 2510-G switches (J9280A). Right now our LAN is set up `192.168.50.2` - `192.168.50.254` on our sub-net (A) and another scope with `192.168.51.2` - `192.168.51.254` sub-net (B) both have sub-net mask of `255.255.255.0`

The same server is our DNS which is `192.168.50.242` and our firewall (watchguard) is the gateway at `192.168.50.1`. Right now the subnet (B) does not have DHCP active so only sub-net (A) is giving a pool.

My problem is that we are trying to have open WiFi on our network and i am assuming that i can use the sub-net (B) for that if i activate it and use sub-net (A) for our staff only. I have noticed that when i set up a static on a client pc and set it to `192.168.51.x` i cannot use the DNS of `192.168.50.242` however i can use `8.8.8.8` and it works fine, i am guessing that because it is on a different subnet? Forgive me as i am very new at this and dont know a lot. Is there easy way with the equipment i have to a accommodate wifi for hundreds of people without causing problems for our staff? (multiple same IP address assigns) I appreciate any and all info!

Answer (score 3):

You need to hack (pun not intended) your issue up into separate pieces and solve them one by one. To do that you need to gather more info about each issue.

Your dns problem in subnet 192.168.51.0/24 is easiest and a good place to start. It is likely a routing problem, a firewall problem or both. Work out your default gateway address for a client on that subnet. For instance, if it is the Watchguard make sure it will a) route between the subnets and b) permit dns queries from the .51-net to the .50-net. You will likely wish to permit more kinds of traffic than that from .51. to .50., but you get the idea.

The wifi is hard to answer based on your info, but a wifi for hundreds of people working simultaneously and getting it to work well does require forethought. It does sound like you wish your access points to work as nat routers, which would mean that solving the dns problem above is key to functionally solving this one. Sizing is another story entirely, once you have acheived basic functionality.

Comment: ok I have the DNS issue working i believe, I can access from 51-50 and remote in to the servers. Now i am wondering if i can add as many scopes as i need? or will my subnet mask need to be adjusted